# Makefile target to add k8s cluster config

Tags: kubernetes, makefile, gnu-make

I want, in one command with **args** to config `kubeconfig`, that is able to connect to k8s cluster.

I tried the following which does not work.

```
cfg:
    mkdir ~/.kube

kube: cfg
    touch config $(ARGS)
```

In the **args the user** should pass the config file **content** of the cluster (kubeconfig).

If there is a shorter way please let me know.

**update**

I've used the following which (from the answer) is partially solve the issue.

```
kube: cfg
    case "$(ARGS)" in \
      ("") printf "Please provide ARGS=/some/path"; exit 1;; \
      (*)  cp "$(ARGS)" /some/where/else;; \
    esac
```

The problem  is because of the `cfg` which is creating the dir in case the user not providing the `args` and in the **second** run when providing the path the dir is already exist and you get an error, is there a way to avoid it ? **something like if the arg is not provided dont run the cfg**

Comment: What would be an example of the content of $(ARGS)?

Comment: @Jens - lets say it's a path to a file, https://github.com/zecke/Kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file.md#components-of-a-kubeconfig-file

Comment: I don't understand anything. `touch` only modifies time stamps (or creates an empty file). It does not make sense to "touch files with the contents of another file". Do you want to create a file with some contents? Then maybe printf or cp is a better approach.

Comment: Ok so with `cp` how would you do it when getting user input for file location?

Comment: Are you asking how to write Make variable values to a file? Or how Make can receive input from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the user input is the pathname of a file. The `make` utility can take variable assignments as arguments, in the form of `make NAME=VALUE`. You refer to these in your `Makefile` as usual, with `$(NAME)`. So something like

```
kube: cfg
    case "$(ARGS)" in \
      ("") printf "Please provide ARGS=/some/path"; exit 1;; \
      (*)  cp "$(ARGS)" /some/where/else;; \
    esac
```

called with

```
make ARGS=/some/path/file kube
```

would then execute `cp /some/path/file /some/where/else`. If that is not what you were asking, please rephrase the question, providing exact details of what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I need , is there a way to validate that the user is providing the args, the problem is that if the user by mistake doesn't provide the `args` and just call `make kube` the previous target is called with the `mkdir kube` and the folder is created , now if he provide the args and run the command as expected, he will get an error as the folder is already created

Comment: @NinaS Yes, you can do that with a bit of shell scripting. I prefer case/in/esac over test. See my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and I got the following error: `user: projects $ make kube
mkdir ~/.kube
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/user/.kube': File exists
make: *** [Makefile:2: cfg] Error 1` the problem i think is because of the `cfg` which is creating the dir in case the user not providing the `args` and in the second run when providing the path it already exist and you get an error, is there a way to avoid it ? something like if the `arg` is not provided dont run the `cfg` . thank you!

Comment: You can use `mkdir -p  ~/.kube` which will not complain if a directory already exists.